# Problem while configure a Firewall and a Startup Script with Deployment Manager template

Tags: templates, google-cloud-platform, google-deployment-manager

I want to configure a Firewall and a Startup Script with Deployment Manager template in `.yaml` file

Below are the steps I need to perform

1. A new Deployment Manager deployment has been created
2. The deployment includes a virtual machine that has an embedded
   startup-script
3. The virtual machine that has a startup-script also has a tag item
   called http
4. A firewall rule exists that allows port 80 (http) traffic and is
   applied using a tag with a value of http
5. The virtual machine responds to web requests using the Apache web
   server
6. Check that Deployment manager includes startup script and firewall
   resources

Below is the sample file i have created, but while deploying the file its showing that step 3 (The virtual machine that has a startup-script also has a tag item called http) was not configured.

Please help me if I missed any thing.

```
- name: my-vm
  type: compute.v1.instance
  properties:
    zone: us-central1-a
    machineType: zones/us-central1-a/machineTypes/n1-standard-1
    sourceRanges: ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    targetTags: ["webserver"]
    allowed:
    - IPProtocol: TCP
    ports: ["80"]
    metadata:
      items:
      - key: startup-script
        value: |
         #! /bin/bash
         apt-get update
         apt-get install -y apache2
         cat <<EOF > /var/www/html/index.html
         <html><body><h1>Welcome to Apache</h1>
         <p>This page was created from a simple startup script!</p>
         </body></html>
    disks:
    - deviceName: boot
      type: PERSISTENT
      boot: true
      autoDelete: true
      initializeParams:
        sourceImage: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/debian-cloud/global/images/debian-9-stretch-v20180814
    networkInterfaces:
    - network: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/qwiklabs-gcp-dee231a39b26c176/global/networks/default
      accessConfigs:
      - name: External NAT
        type: ONE_TO_ONE_NAT
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option "value" should be a string format.

For example:

```
metadata:
      items:
      - key: startup-script
        value: "apt-get update \n apt-get install -y apache2"
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.I am facing issue for step 3: "The virtual machine that has a startup-script also has a tag item called http".Could you please help me what is the correct syntax for adding http tag

Comment: Oh, i got it, are you doing the GCP Challenge? For using tags, at the level of disks, or metadata, you should use: tags: items: ["http"], (array of strings). I have already made a list of tips for doing that challenge in my github: https://github.com/CaothicPechan/GCPArchitectureChallenge :)

Comment: See the jinja file, that is the template for the deployment manager.

Comment: Yes. I am doing GCP challenge. Thanks a lot Chaotic Pechan for these valuable tips

Answer (score 0):

The virtual machine that has a startup-script also has a tag item called http) was not configured.
as it expresses that a tag item as http must be mentioned for your vm instance .
just mention a tags just after zone->machinetype in properties of the vm-instance

```
zone: your-zone
machineType: your-machine-type
    tags:
        items:
        - 'http'
```